# how to go another scene in javafx?

Tags: javafx

My dashboard fxml location is `Dashboard/DashBoardScene.fxml`. I tried to switch from `Login/LoginController` to dashboard screen

```
public void onLoginButtonClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Dashboard/DashBoardScene.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setTitle("ABC");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
    stage.show();
}
```

but i got location is required error?

Comment: That error just means the path to the FXML resource is incorrect. (It is going to search for it relative to the package containing the current class.) I notice you have `Dashboard` in one part and `DashBoard` in another...

Comment: Thanks for Reply...but my FXML path is D:\RestarantApplication\src\RestarantApp\Dashboard\DashBoardScene.fxml. " getCalss.getResorces("Dashboard/DashBordScene.fxml")".is above i mention error whether correct or wrong?

Comment: What package is the current class in?

Comment: this package i have used for that class "RestarantApp.Dashboard"

Comment: Please add that information to the question.

Comment: OK, now you added information to the question that contradicts what you said in the comment... Is the class containing the code you posted in `Login`, or in `RestarantApp.Dashboard`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is in a class in the `RestarantApp.Dashboard` package (BTW, please use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)). Your FXML file is in the same package.

The code `getClass().getResource(...)` will return a URL of a resource that is searched *relative to the current class*. Since the current class and the FXML file are in the same package, all you need is

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DashBoardScene.fxml"));
```

(This assumes the FXML file is being deployed correctly, the resource name is spelled correctly, etc.)

You can also specify an "absolute" path (one that is relative to the classpath) to the resource:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/RestarantApp/Dashboard/DashBoardScene.fxml"));
```

Note here the path begins with a leading `/`.

Comment: @priyadharsini I was basing this on the information you provided in the comment. Then you edited your question and provided information that contradicted that. It's quite difficult to answer a question when you can't answer basic questions about your own code consistently. See update to answer.

Comment: thank you for your response..the problem has been solved..thank you so much